# How to ignore specific MacOS software updates?

Tags: macos, software-update

There are some software updates I'm not interested in, either because I don't use the applications involved or because I don't care.
I uncheck them and click <kbd>Not now</kbd>
The annoying part is that they keep popping up every time there's a new update.
Can't you uncheck them forever so the updates-to-ignore list doesn't keep growing?
[image]

For example, I couldn't care less about stability when *sending slideshows from iPhoto'11 to iDVD*, something I don't do anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just go up to the menu bar and hit Update>Ignore Update (or the keyboard shortcut is apparently just the delete key).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command "softwareupdate --ignore" in terminal. You can first start with a "softwareupdate -l" to get the actual names of the updates (usually something like iPhoto-9.1...) and then use the ignore command to stop them from showing up.

To see everything that binary can do, try running "man softwareupdate".

Comment: `softwareupdate: unrecognized option --ignore`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could delete the applications and Apple won't try to update them anymore.